# Aggregation Mongodb - Calculate the time difference between the two timestamps

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Data in the collection:

```
{
    user:1
    created: 1487593990260
    header: {
        time: 1487593987000
    }
}
{
    user:2
    created: 1487594980677
    header: {
        time: 1487594978000
    }
}
{
    user:3
    created: 1487595199046
    header: {
        time: 1487595197000
    }
}
{
    user:2
    created: 1487595452715
    header: {
        time: 1487595450000
    }
}
{
    user:3
    created: 1487622649917
    header: {
        time: 1487622649000
    }
}
{
    user:1
    created: 1487622654169
    header: {
        time: 1487622654000
    }
}
{
    user:2
    created: 1487623129875
    header: {
        time: 1487623127000
    }
}
{
    user:2
    created: 1487623298718
    header: {
        time: 1487623297000
    }
}
{
    user:1
    created: 1487623336638
    header: {
        time: 1487623335000
    }
}
```

What I'm aiming for:

```
user: 1
    created -> time -> created -> time -> created -> time -> ...
```

And then I want to calculate the time between created -> time -> created and so on...

The last thing I want to do is group them per user to see the time difference. So I can calculate the average time of each user.

But I don't know if it's possible with the aggregation framework?
Or do I have to do this in the client because it is for a chart that will show a chat?

Comment: Are you looking for the difference between each entry or the total difference between the "first" and "last" entry for each user? If it't the first then you are probably better off iterating through the cursor. If the is the second option, then you can simply use the `$first` and `$last` operators of the aggregation framework and then subtract the two numbers.

Comment: I'm looking for the difference between each entry. But than its easier to sort the data in series and process it further in the client. I guess than? @NeilLunn

Comment: I told you already if you want it in "series", then that is called "iterating the cursor". No aggregation process will do that for you.